# Minimizing a Vector - Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, vectors

I've encountered this question in my discussion section and I don't know how to approach/solve this:

$y \in R^n$, $B \in R^{n \times d}$. Compute $x \in R^d$ such that $x$ minimizes $||y-Bx||^2_2$. When is x unique?

The solution given by my TA was difficult to follow, I've attached it as an image.[image]

Firstly, I don't understand how the solution combines $-y^TBx$ and $x^Tb^Ty$ to get $-2y^TBx$. Secondly, I'd greatly appreciate help understanding the solution as a whole.

Comment: Thanks. If you could point out which step you don't understand in the solution, people may quickly help.. :)

Comment: Firstly, where does the $-2y^TBx$ come from?

Comment: This one is easy, simply because $y^TBx$ is a number (i.e. 1-by-1 matrix) so it is equal to its transpose, which you can find in the previous line. Note that $a+a^T=2a$ for any $1\times 1$ matrix $a$. //Can you please summarize *all* the steps that you don't understand in your post? That would be much easier to answer than in comments.